# Why after installing Ubuntu by PXE it never has Internet or Internet Connectivity?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp

I've even trying for weeks to install Ubuntu over the the network. I have been successful at setting up my Ubuntu Server and also I am able to get my clients to pxe boot and everything else is working fine except that after the installation there is no internet. I am having an issue where "iface eth0 inet dhcp" changes to "iface eth0 inet manual" no matter what image I use, I always get the same result why? Why I is there never network connectivity after installation?

I read about it being a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...ty/+bug/388060 and here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...er/+bug/946215

I am not sure what to do is there a guide to fix this issue?

Comment: I want to add that no matter what Ubuntu image I use no matter if I use a Debain or Ubuntu server I always get the same result. I never have internet connection after installation. I don't know if I am skipping a step or not configuring a file or changing a script.

Comment: I have used this tutorial:

http://www.serenux.com/2010/05/howto-setup-your-own-pxe-boot-server-using-ubuntu-server/
http://www.serenux.com/2010/05/howto-get-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-boot-off-a-pxe-server/
http://www.serenux.com/2012/06/howto-fix-networking-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-desktop-from-a-pxe-booted-live-environment/

Comment: Like I said everything works fine except after the installation I never have internet connectivity. I dont know what I am missing, If someone can point me to what I am not doing or some step I might be skipping, I would gladly appreciate it. Is there a special way of installing a live image over the network, some special instructions that I am not aware of? I need help, any help would be appropriated. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager for some reason assumes that since you already have an IP address before you booted into the live session, it isn't needed and goes to sulk in the corner.

To fix the problem, after you've rebooted for the first time after installing Ubuntu via PXE, edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and DELETE the **auto etho** and **iface eth0** lines (leave the "lo" loopback entries).

Save and reboot and Network Manager will magically work again, with working Internet to boot.